# Can we monitor newly added data inside database table using Liquibase?

Tags: java, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate, liquibase-sql

I want to monitor newly added data inside database table using Liquibase. 
I have found out that we can do Create, Insert, update, delete, rollback types of operations on table but I not sure whether we can perform read operation to see actual data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

Liquibase doesn't provide any `<read>` [changes](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/). However, you can always use `<sql>` change and do the following (in fact you may put any native SQL inside this tag):

`<sql> SELECT * FROM users </sql>`

This gives you the ability to read the actual data in your database, but I'm not sure why would you need to just read the data.

Perhaps, you'd want to use the `diff` command. Here's the [documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html) on it.